# ASP.NET MVC4 routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

Can someone show me how to write a route for this controller action?
I'm getting this error and not sure why or how to fix it:
`The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'PID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'`

```
//
// GET: /Account/ExternalLogOn
// https://example.com/Account/ExternalLogOn?Ticket=c4020d4a1b8d4ea0f2c6320885d44ad4eec080fd75&PID=1127326&RUrl=/Home/Info
//
public ActionResult ExternalLogOn(string Ticket, int PID, string Name, string EC, String State, string RUrl)
```

Parameters Name , EC and State are optional. Also, this is GET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `int PID` to `int? PID`

This will make it `nullable` and therefore not required.

**Edit**

I may be wrong but could you change the /Home/Info in your string to %2fHome%2fInfo

I'm thinking it may have a role in this.

Comment: But why would I get that error when I DO pass a PID in the URL?

Comment: That didn't help because when I debug into it, the PID is showing as NULL even when I pass one in the query string. Go figure???

Comment: @MB34 Could you try putting the PID before the Ticket .. may do nothing but lets be sure the entire string doesn't have any issues...

Comment: @MB34 the Ticket? what about the PID?

Comment: I believe that fixed it. Thanks.